# Link two objects and get them one by other

Tags: java, optimization

I have a fairly simple college problem, that i can't wrap my head around

I have two Arrays of objects, lets call them `A` and `B`

`A` can have multiple `B`

i have to implement

```
public void linkThem( A[] aArray, B[] bArray)
{

}


public List<B> getBbyA( A a)
{

}
```

and

```
public List<A> getAbyB( B b)
{

}
```

with least number of iterations!!

Now only solution I can see is to create new class `AB`:

```
class AB
{
    private final A a;
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

    public AB( A a )
    {
       this.a = a;
    }
}
```

in main class add `private static List<AB> ABList = new ArrayList<AB>();`

do `foreach()` on all `A` and `B` and in geters do a lot more `foreach()` (on `AB` and then in `AB` `foreach()` on `bList` )

But this is an very ugly 'Brute force' approach, and i would really like simpler, and less 'system heavy' solution.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem, but read about maps http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html, maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right as xp500 said you should look into Maps.

Very simple solution for your dilemma would be something like:

```
private Map<A,B> AtoB = new HashMap<A,B>();
private Map<A,List<B>> BtoA = new HashMap<A,List<B>>();
```

in 'linking' part you do:

```
public void linkThem( A[] aArray, B[] bArray)
{
    for (A a : aArray)
        for (B b : bArray)
            if( theyAreLinked() )
            {
                AtoB.put( a, b );

                List<B> temp =  BtoA.get(a);
                if(temp == null)
                    temp = new ArrayList<B>();
                temp.add(b);
                BtoA.put( a,temp  ):
            }
}
```

and in getters:

```
public List<B> getB( A a)
{
    return BtoA.get( a );
}

// i think you should only return one A here
public A getA( B b)
{
    return AtoB.get( b );
}
```

But I think if you are into over-optimising there are better solutions here... But as you said this is for college i think this is enough.